# Raspberry Pi Zero WiFi card

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi-driver

I have a problem with installing the TL-WN725N WiFi card for Raspberry Pi Zero. When I enter the command:

`Uname -a`

I get the answer:

> Linux raspberrypi 4.9.41+

[image]

Does anyone know a way to install this WiFi card?

Comment: It's `-O`, not `-0`, if that's what you want to know.

Comment: Ok, I corrected it, but wifi card doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what is happened. This is correct code

```
wget http://www.fars-robotics.net/8188eu-4.9.41-1023.tar.gz
tar xzf 8188eu-4.9.41-1023.tar.gz
./install.sh
```

If you want to downloand drivers you have to connect to raspberry pi your smartphone and turn on USB tethering.

Comment: Not everyone has a phone that supports tethering.  Seems like a design flaw that a cell phone is required to fix this problem

Comment: Ok, but it works :D Thanks